# What is the purpose of anonymous Functions in Javascript/JQuery when it seems I don't need one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let me explain this a little better. I've just started learning JS and Jquery coming from learning java/c for a short while. I'm use to the functions (methods) in those languages and am having a difficult time understanding why certain functions are used in JS. I've read all sorts of tutorials and searched this site but the answers for "why anonymous functions are used" is different than what I'm looking for.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').hide();
});
```

Here with the use of jquery we are hiding the "div" elements with a function. Or here:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $('div').hide();
});
```

The same thing here except when we click on the div it hides it. But here's the thing I'm confused about - why does it need be on click, then a function running "`.hide()`" as opposed to just every time on click it just does "`('div').hide();`"

Or with the first piece of code you just want the 'div' elements hidden, why isn't it just simply hiding the elements with $('div').hide() - why is there the need of a function to do this? You don't need to call the function anywhere else. It just hides it when the document is ready, or with the first example, it hides when you click it.

I've seen this in the practice tutorials on codeacademy and other tutorial videos many times so far, where there are functions that I don't think are needed but are used.

Finally, even a function with a variable like this:

```
$('#add').click(
    function() {
        var value = $('#inp').val(); 
        $('#shoplist').append('<li>' + value + ' </li>'); 
    }
);
```

On click it adds a list element to the unordered list, but i don't understand what the need for function() {} is. `.click()` already makes something happen on click, we run code inside it to happen on click, why does it need a function() as well to make the code inside work?

Comment: The anonymous functions are used to define the code block which will run when the event fires. You're effectively saying to jQuery 'when the `click` event fires, run this anonymous function'.

Comment: Not sure I understand your worries... You don't **need** anonymous functions. But it's a pain to give a name (and move code elsewhere) to every single function you're only going to call in one place.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can see that but why doesn't it just fire the code inside the click `event` anyway? Why does it need a "function" to fire? Like my earlier example its only one line to fire: `$('div').hide();` after a `click` event why doesn't that just fire on the click and requires a function to make it do so.

Comment: Then you aren't asking about anonymous functions. You are asking about callback functions. It isn't the same.

Comment: A function is pretty much the only way to pass around instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.click` function takes a function callback as a parameter. You're telling it what to run when the `click` event occurs.

You couldn't pass the code inside the anonymous function to the `.click` function because it is expecting a function callback.

Comment: Ahhh ok this makes a lot of sense now. I'm not used to functions requiring functions as a parameter. It seems as if these functions perform the action (e.g. click) then fires the code within them, which is what the tutorials seem to have taught but never mentioned they **only** take functions as parameters and since you don't need to name them, leave the names out and make them anonymous.

Comment: Thanks a lot man tried to upvote but don't have enough reputation yet!

Comment: No worries. Glad to help

Answer (score 4):

> why does it need be on click, then a function running ".hide()" as opposed to just every time on click it just does "('div').hide();"

You have to pass something to `click`.

That something is "The function you want to run when the click event happens"

If you instead did:

```
...click( $('div').hide() )
```

then you would:

1. Call `hide()` **immediately** (because that is what `$('div').hide()` does when it is evaluated)
2. Pass the return value to `click`.

The return value isn't a function, so it would either error or be ignored, and clicking would do nothing.

---

The function you pass to `click` doesn't need to be anonymous, but it does need to be a function.

This would be fine, for example:

```
function hide_div() {
    $('div').hide();
}

...click(hide_div)
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I wasn't aware that the parameter I pass in had to be a function, I simply assumed it was a function that can take either one action or lines of actions as a function to be fired. It wasn't specified in the tutorials I read and watched they simply used functions within those click and ready functions that made me wonder.

Answer (score 0):

Lines of code are run in functions, and lines of code are executed when they are called on. When you do this `.click($('div').hide())`, you're calling the function `.hide()` on `$('div')`, giving the result of this function to `.click()`, as opposed to giving this unevaluated line of code to the `.click()` function. Protip, whenever you see `()`, some function is *executed* unless this function is being *declared*. In this case, `.click()` is an `execution` of the function that has been declared as `function click(var callback)`.

There does not exist a single language (that I can think of) where you can actually pass parsed lines of executable code to another function, that are not encapsulated by a method or function. This is simply so because lines of code do not have a type, or definition. How would you define a 'couple of lines of executable code' in a function somewhere?

I challenge you to define a function that does this, and I BET you will either create a function that accepts another function as a parameter, like `click(var callback)`, OR that you will define some sort of parser that tries to parse the lines of code to executable JavaScript and then evaluate it, which is the same as an interpreter, which is what is used to run JavaScript to begin with.